# How do I unlock my ipad?

Tags: ipad

HI I was given an ipad as a gift but my kids played with it and now it is asking for a pin no. every time i turn it on kids cant remember any pin no. so can anyone help me please?

Comment: If your kids cannot remember the password, you will have to restore your iPad to factory settings. If you rebooted your iPad and/or haven't synced with a computer before, your data will be gone.

Comment: cheers for answering so quickly i havent  used it at all so thats not a problem

Comment: My kids are 8&9 i think they didnt know what they were doing "just trying to help dad!""

Comment: Have a look at: [If you forgot the passcode for your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch, or your device is disabled](https://support.apple.com/HT204306)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to restore your iPad to factory settings if you can't remember the password for it. If you didn't make a backup earlier, your data will be gone. Forever. You can find the instructions in this article: [If you forgot the passcode for your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch, or your device is disabled](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306)